# Where can I view active directory failed logon attempts?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-event-log

I do not see any failed logon attempts in my windows sever 2003 security event log (I see only successful ones).  However, I have a user that is getting locked out very often and I need to try to determine why.   Is there a setting that might be hiding the failed login attempts, or a way to view these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your auditing policy is set to only log successful events, you will only get successful events.  Change your auditing policy to log logon failures as well, then look at [these](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18465) Microsoft tools to help you troubleshoot the lockout issue.

Comment: As in this?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814595

Comment: Yes, that is what you are looking to do.